# Boostrap 4.1. Navigation Bar

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

Recently I have followed one Bootstrap tutorial on YouTube.
I was following the code and wrote it exact the same, but I have a slight problem with the navigation bar.

The author clearly had the same code as I recall. When browser is opened in wide screen my navigation bar isnt acting fully responsive.

Menu Icon stays shown and my nav items arent shown inline without the menu icon in the full screen mode.

```html
<!doctype HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9gVQ4dYFwwWSjIDZnLEWnxCjeSWFphJiwGPXr1jddIhOegiu1FwO5qRGvFXOdJZ4" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link href="C:\Users\Filip\Desktop\herbarica\main.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>Herbarica</title>
</head>
<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-mb navbar-light bg-light sticky-top">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html"> <img src="#"></a>
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarResponsive">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse " id="navbarResponsive">
                <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                    <li class="nav-item active">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">About us</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Shop</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-cs/chFZiN24E4KMATLdqdvsezGxaGsi4hLGOzlXwp5UZB1LY//20VyM2taTB4QvJ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-uefMccjFJAIv6A+rW+L4AHf99KvxDjWSu1z9VI8SKNVmz4sk7buKt/6v9KI65qnm" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: did you add the js links?

Comment: yea.

Pls dont mind me. Im first time on this page and Im trying to realise how to put the full code -.- .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Typo Error

It's because you have provided the wrong class

> Change `navbar-expand-mb` to `navbar-expand-md`

---

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>



<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light bg-light sticky-top">
  <div class="container-fluid">

    <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html"> <img src="#"></a>

    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarResponsive">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">
      <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
        <li class="nav-item active">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          Dropdown
        </a>
          <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
            <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>

  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: thats it! Thanks alot. I should focus better next time.

Comment: This happens all the time. So not to worry :)

Answer (score 1):

As a summary

```
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-xl> //navbar vertically on extra large screen
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg> //navbar vertically on large screen
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md> //navbar vertically on medium screen
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm> //navbar vertically on small screen
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm bg-dark navbar-dark">
  <!-- Brand/logo -->
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
    <img src="bird.jpg" alt="logo" style="width:40px;">
  </a>

  <!-- Links -->
  <ul class="navbar-nav">
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link 1</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link 2</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link 3</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>

<div class="container-fluid">
  <h3>Brand / Logo</h3>
  <p>When using the .navbar-brand class on images, Bootstrap 4 will automatically style the image to fit the navbar.</p>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Follow this link https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/bootstrap_navbar.asp

Comment: Can you please tell me how to you type put the code in this text editor.